# Aggregating built artifacts in Teamcity to a single zip

Tags: build, zip, teamcity, artifacts

Aim: Set up an ant/cmd script that will package the artifacts from several builds into a single zip. I plan to do this by setting up a final build configuration that will have a dependency on those several projects.

So all my build configurations build successfully and produce build artifacts on the Build Server @.BuildServer\system\artifacts{PROJECT}{several configurations}.. In my "Artifact Aggregating" configuration, I need to be able to reference what and where those artifacts are using variables that can be used in my ant/cmd script. i.e. I have Project A with configurations w, x, and y; how would I define/construct I variables of these configurations(w,x,y) that can be referenced by build configuration z. I looked at current Teamcity documentation i.e. http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD3/System+Properties+of+a+Build+Configuration#SystemPropertiesofaBuildConfiguration-ref; but I find this doesn't resolve my query.

Is there a way I can set up my artifact paths for configurations w, x and y to make the final task easier?

What would be the best way to accomplish this task? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Couldn't you simply publish Artifacts into same common location? via msbuild copy task or via TC publishArtifacts?

Comment: Can you please eloborate on how you would do this via TC in an answer? This is what I am looking for but there isn't that much document supporting "setting up artifact paths".. 

I could set up the buildserver as an agent that is only allowed to build the "zip artifacts" build configuration; that way it would be easier to determine the location of the artifacts, but then I still have the trouble of locating the latest one, as this directory is assigned a random number. I could do this, but I would end up hacking it in cmd line, which I don't want to do.. There must be a tidier alternative.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to create a zip using artifact paths with:
PROJECT.zip|PROJECT\bin\Release|**\*=>PROJECT\bin

..and nothing happened,I followed the teamcity documentation here: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD3/Build+Artifact 

Which states: 
file_name|directory_name|Ant-like wildcard [ => target_directory ]

I expected to find a zip of the built Release folder. In the artifacts dir on the server.

p.s. I miss maven2

Comment: yeah sure. but sorry for my English )

Answer (score 2):

This is how *we* do that.

1. Create n+1 Configuration(ZIP_ALL) and add dependency for all n projects see [Dependency trigger](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Build+Trigger)
2. Create network share \\server\Build for aggregating project's building results
3. (**you need cleanup strategy for that folder**) - we simply drop all, our teammates create sub folders with SVN rev name (TC sets variable with revision value)
4. For each configuration create msbuild(or ant, or rake) script, that will build and zip (if you need) all output from build
5. Copy zip file or complete Output folder to common location (\\server\Build) see [Copy Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)
6. Create ant script for ZIP_ALL configuration that simply zips all files in common location
7. Publish that to TeamCity via [Artifact Publishing](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD3/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-artPublishing)